# Is my class allocating GPU memory leaking if it throws an exception which is caught?

Tags: exception, error-handling, cuda, resource-leak

I am writing a "error-check" function with is throwing `std::runtime_error` whenever an error is encountered (code samples below).


**Situation:**

Let's say that in `foo` constructor (in file: `fooClass.h` sample below) I was able to successfully set cuda device and allocate gpu memory, but my call to `cudaMemcpy(***)` has returned an error for whatever reason. That means my `errchk(***)` function is throwing an exception and is transferring control to `main()` function (in file: `Start.cpp`).


Because `foo` constructor did not finish it job, no `foo` object was created and `~foo()` destructor was not called, therefore previously allocated gpu resources have been not released.


I know `try` block in `main()` is supposed to de-allocate all resources in reversed order to their initialization (whenever exception is thrown).


**Question #1:**

Does that mean I experienced gpu memory leak? OR somehow `throw`, `try` and `catch` can handle this situation?


**Question #2 (? Opinion based ?):**

I am learning C++ exception system and therefor I would like to know if this is a good idea to **throw exceptions everywhere, and catch them only in `main()` function?**

I think this is worth considering because then I am able to end my program in "natural" way - `return EXIT_FAILURE;` in opposition to `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

---

**ErrorCheck.h: (whole file)**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef __ERROR_CHECK_H__
#define __ERROR_CHECK_H__
#include <stdexcept>

// The function:
template <typename T>
bool errchk(const T check, const char* file, unsigned int line, const char* from, const char* func);

// How To call it:
#define ERRCHK(_check) \
    errchk(_check, __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNC__, #_check)

#endif // !__ERROR_CHECK_H__
```

**ErrorCheck.cpp: (simplified version)**

```
// Include:
#include <cuda.h>              // cudaError_t
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cufft.h>             // cufftResult_t
#include <cublas.h>            // cublasStatus_t
#include <curand_kernel.h>     // curandStatus_t
#include <cusolver_common.h>   // cusolverStatus_t
#include <cusparse.h>          // cusparseStatus_t

#include <stdexcept>
#include "ErrorCheck.h"

// Functions bellow are overloaded 7 times for every error type from headers included above
inline const bool testForError(const Type & check) { return check != SuccessValue; };
inline const char * getErrorName(const Type & error) { /* ... */ };
inline const char * getErrorString(const Type & error) { /* ... */ };

// The function:
template <typename T, T successValue>
void errchk(const T check, const char* file, unsigned int line, const char* from, const char* func)
{
    if (testForError(check)) {

        // generate error description in form of a string.

        throw std::runtime_error(errorDescription);
    }
}

// Instantiations:
template void errchk <bool            > (const bool             check, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * from, const char * func);
template void errchk <cudaError_t     > (const cudaError_t      check, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * from, const char * func);
template void errchk <cufftResult_t   > (const cufftResult_t    check, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * from, const char * func);
template void errchk <cublasStatus_t  > (const cublasStatus_t   check, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * from, const char * func);
template void errchk <curandStatus_t  > (const curandStatus_t   check, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * from, const char * func);
template void errchk <cusolverStatus_t> (const cusolverStatus_t check, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * from, const char * func);
template void errchk <cusparseStatus_t> (const cusparseStatus_t check, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * from, const char * func);
```

**fooClass.h:**

```
#include "ErrorCheck.h"
class foo
{
private:
    float * dev_floatArray;
    float * host_floatArray;

public:
    foo() {
        // Do something...
        ERRCHK(cudaSetDevice(0));
        ERRCHK(cudaMalloc(&dev_floatArray, 10000 * sizeof(float)));
        // Do something...
        ERRCHK(cudaMemcpy(host_floatArray, dev_floatArray, 10000 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        // Do something...
    }
    ~foo() {
        // Do something...
        ERRCHK(cudaFree(dev_floatArray));
        ERRCHK(cudaDeviceReset());
    }
}
```

**Start.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fooClass.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    try {
        foo bar; // constructor of "foo" Class is called.
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error error) {
        cout << error.what() << endl;
        getchar();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever heard about RAII? It is a very usual pattern to handle such problem.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès 
A little embarrassed to admit but never heard of it... But well we learn our whole life. :) Thank you. I think your answer solves both of my questions.

Comment: Don't be embarrassed, you didn't know it, but now you do...

Answer (score 1):

> Does that mean I experienced gpu memory leak?

Yes, it does. You must not allocate resources without ensuring they will eventually be deallocated; and by throwing an exception if the `cudaMemCpy()` fails - you're not making that assurance.

> OR somehow throw, try and catch can handle this situation?

Actually, yes, sort of.. as @Jean-BaptisteYunès suggests, RAII is key. Please read this:

[What destructors are run when the constructor throws an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10212842/1593077)

So, if you could shove your memory allocation and de-allocation into a RAII member of your `foo` class, you would have completed its construction, and thus its destructor - which deallocates - would have run on exiting the `foo()` scope, even with an exception.

At this point I'll say that you're reinventing the wheel with some of the code you're writing. You can find both a mechanism for wrapping CUDA errors with exceptions and a unique-pointer-like RAII holder for your allocated memory in my [cuda-api-wrappers](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/) library*. So you would have something like:

```
class foo {
public:
    using element_type = float;
    enum : size_t { num_elements };
protected:
    struct {
        cuda::memory::device::unique_ptr<element_type> device;
        cuda::memory::host::unique_ptr<element_type>   host;
    } data;

public:
    foo() : data( {
        cuda::memory::device::make_unique<element_type[]>(
            cuda::device::default_device_id, 
            num_elements
        ),
        cuda::memory::host::make_unique(num_elements)
    } )
    {
        // Do something...
        cuda::memory::copy(
            data.host.get(), data.device.get(), num_elements * sizeof(element_type)
        );
        // Do something...
    }
    ~foo() {
        // Do something...

        // ERRCHK(cudaFree(dev_floatArray));
        // No need to free anything! It's magic!

        // ERRCHK(cudaDeviceReset());
        // Don't reset your device you really need to - and
        // you don't need to.
    }
}
```

Another approach you could consider, instead of a RAII class for holding memory, is Andrei Alexandrescu's 'Scope Guard' mechanism. He explains it (well, the latest version of it) in this video:

[CppCon 2015: Andrei Alexandrescu - Declarative Control Flow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjTrfoiB0MQ)

> Is it a good idea to throw exceptions everywhere, and catch them only in main() function?

Make that a separate question, because the answer is not a simple yes/no. Actually, there are enough questions and answers here on SO which cover that, I think.

<sub>* - Other libraries may also provide something similar, e.g. Thrust, perhaps; but with this one you're not bound to complex abstractions, just CUDA Runtime API wrappers.)</sub>