# How to free dynamic memory if exception occurs in constructor?

Tags: c++

I came across a situation where constructor allocated the dynamic memory and if any exception occurs in the constructor, it was not freeing the dynamically allocated memory. To avoid such situation I used unique_ptr, and it is able to free the memory properly.

To showcase the situation here is a dummy code for that.

```
class ExceptionInConstructor
{
 unique_ptr<int> a;
public:
    ExceptionInConstructor()
    {
        a = std::unique_ptr<int>( new int(10));
        cout <<"Constructor called. Value of a is "<< *a<<endl;
        //some exception occurs after the mrmory allocation
        throw exception();
    }
    ~ExceptionInConstructor()
    {
        cout << "Dest called()"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{ 
    try
    {       
        ExceptionInConstructor ex; 
    }
    catch(...)
    {}  
    return 0;
 }
```

Is it a correct and efficient way for such a situation or is there any better option for such a scenario?

Edit 1: Removed the commented code in destructor which was left by mistake

Comment: That's exactly the purpose of using smart pointers. _" it was not freeing the dynamically allocated memory. "_ How (which tool) did you use to observe that?

Comment: ... and the RAII idiom in general

Comment: In the particular case you show, there is no need.   When the exception is thrown, the destructor of `unique_ptr` releases the object `a` and the dynamically allocated object (from `new int (10)`) that it manages.    As far as `main()` is concerned, once the exception is thrown, the object `ex` never existed.   It is generally considered better to initialise the member `a` in the constructor's initialiser list, rather than in the constructor body, though.

Comment: [The rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) and [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) helps solve this problem very nicely.

Comment: @WhozCraig: OP uses `std::unique_ptr<int>` (and not `unique_ptr<int[]>`) (and use it as is) so it seems intended.

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10212842/4944425

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I used MS Visual Studio in debug mode and confirmed without a smart pointer, it is not releasing the memory allocated for integer

Comment: @santoshkumar without a smart pointer, the memory won't be released *regardless* of whether an exception is thrown unless you *specifically* do so (and there's no place to do so unless you try/catch in the ctor). The order of operations in throwing out of a constructor is specific. Nothing that didn't complete its constructor *ever* has its destructor fired. Your object did not complete construction, but the members *did*. Their destructors are fired in reverse order of member decl in the class. For a simple pointer, that amounts to nada. A smart pointer member will release it's goods.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is exactly the point and intended use case for smart pointers and [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) in general.

Also note that your `delete a` in your destructor is wrong in any case as the `unique_ptr` is not a pointer itself. Relatedly, destructors are also not called if there is an exception in the constructor.

Comment: "delete a" was left by mistake added for the case where it was not with smart pointer, which I removed it. 



@inf
Yes, I understand that destructor won't be called in case of exception in the constructor. That was the reason why it was not freeing the memory allocated for int variable without uniqe_ptr.