# Object in smart pointer is not deleted after stack unwinding

Tags: c++, exception, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I wrote a small program, to check the difference between creating `shared_ptr` via `new` and `make_shared()` function in case of exceptions. I read everywhere that via `make_shared()` it is an exception-safe.

But the interesting thing about both these cases is that the destructor in both cases is not called after stack unwinding? Am I missed something? Thanks in advance.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Car
{
public:
    Car() { cout << "Car constructor!" << endl; throw std::runtime_error("Oops"); }
    ~Car() { cout << "Car destructor!" << endl; }
};

void doProcessing()
{
//    std::shared_ptr<Car> sp(new Car());
    std::shared_ptr<Car> sp2 = std::make_shared<Car>();
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        doProcessing();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Object lifetime _begins_ when the constructor successfully completes.  If the constructor throws, it was not constructed and was never alive, is not an object, does not exist, and cannot be destructed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oh, I expected some code demo behind the link and lazily didnt open it ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 lols

Comment: Interesting philosophical point here: If you destroy an object that doesn't exist does it continue to not exist, or does it not exist any more> :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What object?

The only object in a smart pointer here did not actually complete construction, because its constructor threw. It doesn't exist.

You don't need smart pointers to demonstrate this. Just throw from any constructor and you'll see that [the destructor body is not invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10212864/560648).

Comment: Thanks, I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add an answer addressing "I read everywhere that via make_shared() it is an exception-safe" part of your question, the rest is already answered by Lightness Races in Orbit.

Difference between make_share and shared_ptr(new Car) can be demonstrated by below program.

```
class Car
{
public:
    Car() { cout << "Car constructor!" << endl; throw std::runtime_error("Car oops"); }
    ~Car() { cout << "Car destructor!" << endl; }
};

class Bycicle
{
public:
    Bycicle() { cout << "Bycicle constructor!, does not throw" << endl;}
    ~Bycicle() { cout << "Bycicle destructor!" << endl; }
};

void doProcessing(std::shared_ptr<Car> /*carPtr*/, std::shared_ptr<Bycicle> /*bPtr*/)
{

}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        doProcessing(std::shared_ptr<Car>(new Car), std::shared_ptr<Bycicle>(new Bycicle));
    }
    catch(std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "Ex is " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Until C++17, compiler is allowed to make following function calls (in the order described)

-- Call `new Bycicle` along with the constructor of Bycicle but **NOT** call ctor of `shared_ptr`.

-- Call the constructor of Car which throws.

In this case, as pointed out Car was never fully constructed so it won't leak. However constructor of Bycicle was fully executed and it **does** leak (since shared_ptr does **NOT** yet own the object).

Calling `doProcessing(std::make_shared<Car>(), std::make_shared<Bycicle>());` guarantees that ownership of **fully** allocated objects is passed to the shared_ptr.

**Final Note:** This is not applicable since C++ 17, because C++ 17 guarantees that arguments are evaluated fully (order in which they are evaluated is still not guaranteed).

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I have full picture.